# How to dispose a list of text editing controllers in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to know what is the right way to dispose all text editing controllers in a list in flutter?

```dart
List<TextEditingController> controllers = [];
```

I tried this, but it's not working. What should be the correct approach for it?

```dart
dispose(){
 for(TextEditingController controller in controllers){
     controller.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: You can also declare each variable one by one *TextEditingController controller1 = [];*  and dispose them.

Comment: `controllers` refers to the list of controllers. Use `controller.dispose()`

Comment: @JustinW that was a typo mistake from my end in question, corrected it

Comment: Where is the super call to the dispose method, and the override annotation?

Comment: @WilsonToribio controllers are being created dynamically

Comment: @YusufRaza did you get specific error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to call `dispose` on your `List<TextEditingController>`and not on your `TextEditingController`. You need to change it inside your for loop body.

```
dispose() {
 for(final TextEditingController controller in controllers){
     controller.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling on wrong variable:

```
@override
void dispose() {
  for (TextEditingController controller in controllers) {
      controller.dispose(); //<-- change this
  }
  super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: @YusufRaza it seems you are using dispose in a wrong way, can you update the question and add the full code of your class?